# How can I systematically figure out the DLL that a Python package is looking for?

Tags: python, dll, pyqt, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I have a data acquisition software that uses PyQt5 and some other libraries. I use cx_freeze to freeze the program to an executable. The program works fine with all clients (which is like less than 10), except for this guy in South Korea. He's getting this error:

```
D:\Acquirer\Acquirer.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
  File "AcquirerLibs/acquirer.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\BoxDataAcquisition\AcquirerLibs\AcquisitionWindow.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\BoxDataAcquisition\AcquirerLibs\DataAcquire.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\BoxDataAcquisition\AcquirerLibs\DataCollected.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\BoxDataAcquisition\AcquirerLibs\Dataset.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的程序。
```

That non-english text is (cannot find program/dll) as the guy says.

When following `Dataset.py` to line 4, it's basically this:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
```

I'd like to point out that I included many DLLs manually during my freezing process, including some from intel mkl and others from Qt. I made sure that the file QtGui.dll is also there. But now I'm completely unable to understand what's missing.

The problem is not that there's a dll missing. The problem is that I don't seem to find a way to systematically track the missing file and provide it.

**What I tried:**

- I tried giving him all `Qt*.dll` files to copy them beside the executable, but that didn't help.
- I tried to look into the source of QtGui, to find what `ctypes` imports it has. But ctypes was not even imported in `QtGui.pyi`.

Is there some kind of recipe I could give him to do, so that he could find out exactly what DLL is missing?

Comment: I had a simillar issue and ended up using Pyinstaller instead of cx_freeze. Sorry that I can't give you a better answer :/ pyinstaller had issues with pyqt5 up to 2 months ago but all them seem fixed now.

Comment: @Saelyth I got that user to install Anaconda, and the program didn't work even there as a script... so it's a problem in his system somehow...

Comment: Might be a pathing issue with symbols, maybe? If he tries to launch the scripts from a folder named 找 (or his local username) it may fail due to encoding...? I'm playing guessing game here while we wait for someone that can help you.

Comment: @Saelyth Actually I thought of that. As you see, the program is installed in `D:\Acquirer`. Hopefully someone will be able to place the correct guess. I asked the guy to format his computer. I formatted a computer here and it worked fine right after Windows installation.

Comment: try to use Dependency Walker to see which dll is missing